# PSD em 1920px ficando enorme em resolução 1366px

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, psd

Atualmente tenho passado a receber PSDs com resolução de 1920px ou seja, o site feito para telas maiores, porém os designers tem me enviado o site de fato feito nesse tamanho, ou seja, fontes, imagens e etc, tudo preparado para tela de 1920px porém se eu corto as imagens do PSD e as insiro no HTML, se utilizo as medidas que estão no PSD (altura, largura, espaçamentos e etc.) para os elementos, o site fica extremamente grande em telas de 1366 (que inclusive são as telas que tenho aqui no escritório e que desenvolvo os sites). Já discuti a questão com um design mas como na maioria das vezes nossos planetas são distintos (hehe) fica complicadíssimo chegar a uma conclusão. Enfim, será que alguém tem alguma informação para me passar? Nesse momento eu de fato não sei se sou eu (programador) que estou sem conhecimento necessário do assunto ou se são os designers que estão trabalhando comigo.

Para poder "mascarar" o problema eu estou criando uma cópia do PSD redimensionando-o para 1360 e é a partir dele que eu tiro as medidas que preciso como altura, largura, espaçamentos e etc. As imagens eu continuo cropando do PSD de 1920 porém eu defino a largura (parâmetro width na tag img) de acordo com o PSD em 1360 (deu para entender?).

Toda informação sobre o assunto seria de excelente ajuda. Obrigado a todos desde já.

Comment: caso queira apenas redimensionar as imagens apenas pelo photoshop, converta-as para objetos inteligentes, dê dois cliques no ícone junto a imagem no painel de elementos do PS, ele irá abrir em uma nova guia, crie um novo arquivo com o tamanho desejado, arraste a imagem separada para dentro do arquivo, aperte Ctrl+T para redimensionar e cubra a parte que é necessária apenas

Comment: mas é como o @LeonFreire falou, é bom tomar conhecimento de design responsivo, assim, você consegue usar qualquer coisa de qualquer tamanho, em várias resoluções diferentes, sem nunca estourar/desrespeitar o layout

Comment: Você já verificou o DPI no arquivo PSD? Se estiver maior que 72, quando você exportar ele vai ter um aspecto maior do que a resolução original. Pelo menos eu passei pelo mesmo problema que você, porém com o illustrator. O arquivo.ai era exportado para imagem usando 150dpi em 1920px, porém a imagem gerada tinha mais de 3000px. Tente ver se não é isso que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa tomar conhecimento de sites responsivos.
O que está acontecendo no seu caso, é que usando tamanhos fixos (provavelmente para tudo). Nesse caso o seu site funcionará perfeitamente apenas para um tamanho de tela.

Você deve aprender a usar % para medidas e tomar conhecimento de [Media Queries](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/). Media Queries, em resumo, são a melhor forma de, em CSS, você adaptar seu site para diferentes telas, com um CSS exclusivo por tamanho.

Como eu imagino que você esteja fazendo sites através de adaptação de telas de PSD, você pode pegar a arte que está em alta qualidade para sites (1920px) e diminuí-las pelo CSS em Media Queries para outras resoluções, ou simplesmente usar %.

### EDIT

Para alcançar algo semelhante ao que você está propondo, você vai precisar retirar os limites impostos pela tela e colocar tamanhos que você gostaria que fossem usados para monitores grandes e os gigantes de uma vez só.

Por exemplo, na parte principal do conteúdo, seu CSS tem medidas como:

```
.home main .container {
    max-width: 1055px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

Isso estabelece um limite de tamanho pra tela, mas eu vejo que ele quer algo enorme, ocupando toda a tela. Então você iria precisar retirar isso. Exemplo:

```
.home main .container {
    max-width: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 90vw; /* ou 100vw dependendo da situação */
}
```

No sponsor seria o mesmo:

```
.home .sponsors .container {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Acho que começando com essa ideia você consegue matar o restante, mas qualquer dúvida a mais, só comentar.

Comment: Olá Leon, antes de mais nada obrigado pela resposta, veja bem, eu já uso media queries, na verdade acabei simplificando meu trabalho dentro de 3 ambientes, sejam eles, "max-width: 767px", "max-width: 991px" e "max-width: 1199px", eu cheguei a essa conclusão pois o Bootstrap usa esses break points e eu uso o Bootstrap em todos meus projetos.

Comment: @LeandroBerg Entendi. Mas você está trabalhando com medidas em "%" ou "vw"?

Comment: Olha, os meus elementos acabam sendo dimensionados dentro do container, e o container esta em % (Bootstrap grid). A questão é que o container do Bootstrap só chega a 1140 e os PSDs tem chegado bem maiores que isso, sacou?

Comment: @LeandroBerg tem como você mandar um exemplo? Um fiddle ou coisa assim para eu poder ajudar? Respondendo assim sem ver, estou apenas supondo o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Então, faz o seguinte, acesse aqui o jpg export que fiz do PSD que estou trabalhando:

http://virtuemasters.com.br/projetos/k08/k08-home.jpg

E aqui veja o projeto sendo desenvolvido:

http://virtuemasters.com.br/projetos/k08

Veja se consegue entender, no JPG / PSD nesse caso, esta tudo muito maior (abra o JPG com zoom 100% para ver isso) as fontes são maiores, os elementos e etc. Agora já no HTML tudo esta menor (já que eu acabei reduzindo para caber na tela de 1360. E o cliente está reclamando que esta tudo pequeno :/ entende? Ele deseja que eu faça do tamanho do PSD.

Comment: @LeandroBerg Entendi a situação. Clássico exemplo de cliente doido que não entende o conceito de responsividade! Está bem melhor, inclusive no meu monitor, da forma que está feito no seu trabalho. Mas vou atualizar a minha resposta com algumas rápidas sugestões de como você pode "simular" o efeito desejado. (Embora eu realmente só faria isso pra agradar cliente. Geralmente não assino embaixo desse tipo de coisa. Hahaha...) Já já te dou um toque aqui e você checa.

Comment: @LeandroBerg Editado. Checa aí!

Comment: Sim sim, no caso fui eu mesmo que fiz a delimitação de 1055px, isso justamente para poder ficar algo mais parecido com o PSD dele porém com mais ou menos 30% a menos de tamanho/resolução vamos assim dizer, entende? Mas após todo o meu trabalho redefinindo tudo para caber na tela o cliente insiste em dizer que o PSD esta correto e que nossa equipe é que não entende de design responsivo :/ Para você ter ideia, ele insistiu tanto nisso que abri essa question aqui para poder ver a opinião da comunidade. Bem, nesse caso o PSD está de fato grande e fora da grid certo?

Comment: Veja aqui outro PSD que estou trabalhando e tendo o mesmo problema (e olha que esse daqui é de outro design):

http://virtuemasters.com.br/projetos/k08/global-moms-relay.jpg

Veja que também está em 1920px porém os elementos estão fora do padrão e ficarão grandes em resoluções menores.

Comment: @LeandroBerg Na minha opinião sim. O seu trabalho parece estar bem adequado ao meu monitor do trabalho, que está em 1360x768 e parece bem fiel à imagem. Imagino que pra agradar os caras você vá ter que explodir alguns tamanhos.

Comment: @LeandroBerg É comum os trabalhos virem em 1920px para maior qualidade. O problema é os clientes cismarem com a responsividade. Mas tem que agradar, né? Tenta deixar tudo enorme da forma que eles querem. Como eu disse, eu faço da forma que querem, mas quando não me agrada pessoalmente, eu não assino. Já aconteceu algumas vezes.